# Cordova build android fails after upgrading to cordova-android 11

Tags: android, cordova

I'm currently upgrading cordova (and its platforms) in an existing project.
After upgrading from cordova-android from 9.x to 11.x I get some build errors:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade
   > Android resource linking failed
     C:\Users\OBurger\.gradle\caches\transforms-3\5c55b34766402f38a5e46b43ac71f280\transformed\jetified-core-splashscreen-1.0.0\res\values-v31\values-v31.xml:3:5-9:13: AAPT: error: style attribute 'android:attr/windowSplashScreenAnimatedIcon' not found.

     C:\Users\OBurger\.gradle\caches\transforms-3\5c55b34766402f38a5e46b43ac71f280\transformed\jetified-core-splashscreen-1.0.0\res\values-v31\values-v31.xml:3:5-9:13: AAPT: error: style attribute 'android:attr/windowSplashScreenBackground' not found.

     C:\Users\OBurger\.gradle\caches\transforms-3\5c55b34766402f38a5e46b43ac71f280\transformed\jetified-core-splashscreen-1.0.0\res\values-v31\values-v31.xml:3:5-9:13: AAPT: error: style attribute 'android:attr/windowSplashScreenAnimationDuration' not found.

     C:\Users\OBurger\.gradle\caches\transforms-3\5c55b34766402f38a5e46b43ac71f280\transformed\jetified-core-splashscreen-1.0.0\res\values-v31\values-v31.xml:10:5-14:13: AAPT: error: style attribute 'android:attr/windowSplashScreenIconBackgroundColor' not found.

     C:\Users\OBurger\.gradle\caches\transforms-3\4e55571a2aca20a3df79838283759989\transformed\core-1.7.0\res\values\values.xml:105:5-114:25: AAPT: error: resource android:attr/lStar not found.
```

I already followed the steps for the cordova-android upgrade described here: https://ionic.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/7891143965975-Migrating-to-Cordova-Android-11

I also added a dependency for "androidx.core:core-splashscreen:1.0.0" in build.gradle